# JSON iteration using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, rest, api

I have called rest api through ajax, i get the response from api in json format, now i want to display the data on my webpage.
I want to show as follows

```
scheduled
driver_count:
passenger_count:

active
driver_count:
passenger_count:
```

My code as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            asyn: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "http://10.26.32.11/api/rating-service/rate/current/gettrips",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            callback: 'callback',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                var jso = parseJSON(data);
                console.log(jso);                    

            }
        });

    });
```

JSON reply

```
{
"scheduled": {
    "driver_count": 1,
    "passenger_count": 1
},
"active": {
    "driver_count": 0,
    "passenger_count": 0
}
```

}

Comment: Then just create some html nodes like a `<p>` - give the nodes an id, or some way of getting the specific node of the html page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById - Then use javascript to set the innertext. in the onload. If you are serving the data from a web server, you can build the hmtl on the fly, then serve that up

Comment: So what is the specific problem or question?

Comment: Could you pls help me to display schedule & active counts in a span or any html element

Comment: Its showing an error
" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new variable as key_count with value and use that variable

```js
obj = {
"scheduled": {
    "driver_count": 1,
    "passenger_count": 1
},
"active": {
    "driver_count": 0,
    "passenger_count": 0
}}
makeFlatModel(obj);
console.log(obj);

function makeFlatModel(jsonObject){
 var sum=0;
 for(var propertyName in jsonObject){
  if(typeof jsonObject[propertyName] =='object'){
   jsonObject[propertyName+"_count"] = makeFlatModel(jsonObject[propertyName]);
  }else{
   sum+= jsonObject[propertyName];
  }
 } 
  return sum;

}
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
// jsonreplay is the string of json you got from the server
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonreplay)
// in javascript you can use for loop to iterate properties
for(var propertyName in obj){
   console.log(propertyName+":");
   for(var internalPropertyName in obj[propertyName]){
      console.log(internalPropertyName + ":"+obj[propertyName][internalPropertyName]);
   }
}
```

Comment: If the replay JSON structure is constant you can use the answer @Dalli gave you.

Comment: Dint understand, pls explain

Comment: How can i imperilment in my code to get only nos from response

Answer (score 0):

You can access your variables as per below

```
jso.active.driver_count // will print out your value
```

Comment: How can i use it, pls provide sample

Answer (score 0):

if you did not make this api by yourself, you can loop object by

```
var jsobj = {
            "scheduled": {
                            "driver_count": 1,
                            "passenger_count": 1
                         },
            "active":    {
                         "driver_count": 0,
                         "passenger_count": 0
                         }
            };

for (var key in jsobj) {
    if (jsobj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key); //scheduled, active
        var d_cnt = jsobj[key]['driver_count'];
        var p_cnt = jsobj[key]['passenger_count'];
    }
}
```

but if you can edit api output script, this structure will make life easier:

```
var objList = [{
            "type" : "scheduled", 
            "driver_count": 1,
            "passenger_count": 1
          },{
            "type": "active",
            "driver_count": 0,
            "passenger_count": 0
          }];
```