# Iterate JSON & takeout each value separately

Tags: jquery, json

I get the expected results in console.log, now i want to display the results in span
As follows 
Scheduled
Driver:
Passenger:
Active
Driver:
Passenger:

My working code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        asyn: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "apilink",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        callback: 'callback',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            //console.log(result)
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result))
            for (var propertyName in obj) {
                console.log(propertyName + ":");
                for (var internalPropertyName in obj[propertyName]) {
                    console.log(internalPropertyName + ":" + obj[propertyName][internalPropertyName]);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a specific problem or just looking for someone to write code for you?

Comment: Do u have fixed json  or dynamic structure? also add the solution u tried, so that we can point out the issue in that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON iteration using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51874696/json-iteration-using-jquery)

Comment: Pls check, i've tried above code

Comment: @VishalFreelancer : you can keep existing object as it and new varibles for count and use it in your ui/display page as https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893734/4225796

Answer (score 0):

You can create one function and call this function in ur ajax response.
THis will add new keys for you as "scheduled_count" and "active_count"

you can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        asyn: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        url: "http://10.26.32.11/api/rating-service/rate/current/gettrips",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        callback: 'callback',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            //console.log(result)
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result))
             makeFlatModel(obj);
        }
    });
```

```js
// For testing no need to add in code
jsobj  = {
"scheduled": {
    "driver_count": 1,
    "passenger_count": 1
},
"active": {
    "driver_count": 0,
    "passenger_count": 0
}}
makeFlatModel(jsobj );
console.log(jsobj );
// For testing code ends

// add this function in your code


function makeFlatModel(jsonObject){
 var sum=0;
 for(var propertyName in jsonObject){
  if(typeof jsonObject[propertyName] =='object'){
   jsonObject[propertyName+"_count"] = makeFlatModel(jsonObject[propertyName]);
  }else{
   sum+= jsonObject[propertyName];
  }
 } 
  return sum;

}
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: I've edit my question with my current working code, it shows expected results in console.log, now i want to show each vale in html element. Pls help me out in this.

Comment: @VishalFreelancer in your code you can call "obj = makeFlatModel(obj );" instate of for loop, so you will get object with  "scheduled_count" and "active_count", you can use this variable on your html as you was planning to use scheduled or active

Comment: @VishalFreelancer : do you know how to display object values in html?

Comment: @VishalFreelancer : updated the answer, now your object has more field which you can use to display in html

Comment: @VishalFreelancer i have updated my answer, And after makeFlatModel(obj );  obj field contain two more fields so you can display this value in html. What is your exact issue then

Comment: Sorry, I dint understand, i'm confused actually

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automate the task, you can loop through the keys like in my example below,

```js
    var obj = {
        "scheduled": {
            "driver_count": 1,
            "passenger_count": 5
        },
        "active": {
            "driver_count": 1,
            "passenger_count": 2
        }
    }
    
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    
    keys.forEach(function(key){
     var innerKeys = Object.keys(obj[key]);

        var s = key;
        s = s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
     var head = s + ": ";
      
      innerKeys.forEach(function(key, idx){
       head+= (idx > 0 ? "+" : "") + key.split("_")[0];
      });
      
      innerKeys.forEach(function(innerKey){
        var s = innerKey.split("_")[0];
        s = s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
       head+="\n" + s + ": " + obj[key][innerKey]; 
      })
      
      
      console.log(head)
    })
```

This will generate the keys for you and get the values as well generating the exact output you've asked.

Comment: How to display each values in html element, Like
Scheduled
Driver:
Passenger:

Active
Driver:
Passenger: